# accessing the user profile from table

Tags: php, mysql, database, url, profile

I made a table to display all the patients from the database and I want when we click on the "nom patient" redirect to the profile of the selected patient so  Itry to  send the "nom patient" with the url to the profile.php page

```
if($total_row > 0)
 {
foreach($result as $row)
{
    $r=$row["NomPatient"];
    $output .= '
    <tr>
        <td width="40%">'.$row["Username_Titeur"].'</td>
        <td width="40%">'.$row["PrenomPatient"].'</td>

         <td width="40%"><a href=" profile.php?link='. $r.'" >'.$r.'</a></td>



    </tr>
    ';
    }
   }
```

profile.php

```
<?php 
        include('../../database_connection.php');
        if ($_GET['link']==$r)
           {
         echo "Link 1 Clicked";
           } else {
            echo "Link 2 Clicked";
             }
```

But it does not work plaese any help

Comment: Could you describe the error or the output that you get ?

Comment: "it does not work" doesn't really help us to know much about your issue. please be more specific about the error that you are having. what's not working? does it even retrieve the values from the DB?